# Make a dynamic link that changes page it references

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, hyperlink

I would like to randomly link to any pages x, this is the code that I have written so far and it does not work...any recommendations??

```
var page1link = "pages/sketches.php";
var page2link = "pages/photography.php";
var page3link = "pages/defined.php";
var page4link = "pages/spectacle2.php"; 
var list = [page1link, page2link,page3link, page4link];
var number = list[Math.floor(Math.random()*list.length)];
var randomlink =list[number];

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("mylink").href = 'randomlink';
};
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <container>
        <h1>
            <a href='randomlink' id='mylink'> Click Me</a>
        </h1>
    </container>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you declared `randomizer` anywhere? If so, what does it do?

Comment: `'randomlink' !== randomlink` unless `randomlink = 'randomlink';`

Comment: Javascript arrays don't have a size() method.

Comment: @epascarello...i changed the value of number to this: var number = list[Math.floor(Math.random()*list.length)]; It still does not work and i get this error: The requested URL /Personal Website/randomlink was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var page1link = "pages/sketches.php";
var page2link = "pages/photography.php";
var page3link = "pages/defined.php";
var page4link = "pages/spectacle2.php"; 
var list = [page1link, page2link,page3link, page4link];
var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * list.length));
var randomlink = list[number];
function myFunction(){
 document.getElementById("mylink").href = 'randomlink';
};
```

Comment: it doesnt work...Not Found

The requested URL /Personal Website/randomlink was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body >
    <container>
        <h1>
            <a href="#" id='mylink'> Click Me</a>
        </h1>
    </container>

<script>
    function myFunction(){
        var page1link = "pages/sketches.php";
        var page2link = "pages/photography.php";
        var page3link = "pages/defined.php";
        var page4link = "pages/spectacle2.php"; 
        var list = [page1link, page2link,page3link, page4link];
        var randomlink =list[Math.floor(Math.random()*list.length)];
        document.getElementById("mylink").href = randomlink;
    }
    window.onload = myFunction;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```